# Error while duplicating a view: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, illegalstateexception

In my `RecylcerAdapter`, I want to duplicate a `TextView`.

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains a `TexView`. All I want is to dynamically duplicate this `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout`, so that I have 10 `TextView`s inside the `LinearLayout`.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tags_ll"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tags"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="عمومی"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_with_background"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

MyViewHolder in RecyclerView:

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tags);
    tags_ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tags_ll);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TextView rowTextView = new TextView(view.getContext());
        //Clone the new textview, get all the properties of the existing textview
        rowTextView = tags;
        rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);
        tags_ll.addView(rowTextView);

    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I want all the properties of the existing textview to be copied to the newly created TextViews.

Comment: What is that supposed to be? `rowTextView = tags;`

Comment: I want to copy the already existing textview to this new text view. I want all the property of the existing textview to be copied to the new textviews.

Comment: This is java. This is not how you copy properties from one object to another

Comment: So how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: You have to create a new textview and copy the "properties" that you want via get and set methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong, you can't copy the `TextView` properties with `rowTextView = tags;`, you're just replacing `rowTextView` TextView with `tags` one.

You need to set the new `TextView` properties from your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TextView rowTextView = new TextView(view.getContext());
    //set the new TextView properties from code
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);
    tags_ll.addView(rowTextView);

}
```

**Or**

You can create an xml layout containing just a `TextView` with the desired attributes, and inflate it in your for-loop.

eg:

`my_text_view.xml` :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="عمومی"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_with_background"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

In your `ViewHolder` :

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      TextView rowTextView= (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, null, false);
      rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);
      tags_ll.addView(rowTextView);

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this error is because,

```
tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tags);
TextView rowTextView = new TextView(view.getContext());
rowTextView = tags;
tags_ll.addView(rowTextView);  // tag.ll has already a child with id = tag
```

When you copy the reference of that object to your new TextView "rowTextView" now both tags, and rowTextView refer to same Object which is already present in tag.ll LinearLayout, Which is why its throws an error.

If your need is just to implement a list with recyclerViewAdapter, than you are making it very complex, no need to get a TextView from the context when you are just going to assign a new reference to that TextView variable.

If you have latest AndroidStudio installed you can just create a new fragment with list, and Android Studio will provide you with a good example how to use RecyclerView Adapter to populate List. or view this link

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/

Hope i helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong - this line:

```
rowTextView = tags;
```

will not copy the first TextView. This will make the new reference to point to the original textView and then you will find yourself adding the original textView in the layout again, causing the error.

What you should do is create your new textView and add its properties by using the original textView like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     TextView rowTextView = new TextView(view.getContext());
     rowTextView.setText(tags.getText());
     rowTextView.setGravity(tags.getGravity());
     //set all other properties like this: rowTextView.setOther(tags.getOther())...
     tags_ll.addView(rowTextView)
}
```